# How can I avoid validating user input 3 times - on the form javascript, in the controller and in the model

Tags: forms, validation, phalcon

What is the best way to validate user data without repeating your code all over the place? Right now, I have to write my validation code in 3 different places.

I have to validate the data in Javascript to provide real time validation - **That's not a valid email,** or **That email is in use!** This is performed by some Javascript code on the page.

I have to validate the data in the controller to ensure that the data is valid - **That's not a valid email!** This is done by the 'form' object that manages the posted data. It has validators for its fields and ensures they all pass validation.

Lastly, I have to validate in the model to ensure that the data is unique (Sometimes) - **That email is in use!** This is done in the model, because the form object is not supposed to access the database for this sort of information.

What do I do here?

I am using Phalcon, incase that model validator stuff seems strange (Phalcon seems to be setup this way)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide where you validate data. You should have 2 spots for it. First is user side. But i guess you already know - never trust user side. So you have to re-validate it on server-side. Just decide where you do that. You can do it in Model, you can do it in Controller, but to do it everywhere - that's should not be happening.

On user side you can use default html5 input type="email" and it will validate that user inputs an email.

My last tactic is to have validation plugin, which validates all the input.

my plugin is something like:

```
<?php
//namespace App\Plugins;

use Phalcon\Validation,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Url,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\StringLength;

class ValidateInput
{
    public function validate_field($field_name, $value)
    {
        $field_name = strtolower($field_name);
        $method = 'validate_' . $field_name;
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method($value);
        }
        error_log('#d5s4f5s method "' . $method . '" does not exist. Please create one.');
        return false;
    }

    private function validate_name($value)
    {
        $value = trim($value);
        if (!preg_match('~^(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}\s.]+)+$~u', $value) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private function validate_ssl($value)
    {
        if (in_array($value, array('0', '1'))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    .....
```

and then anything what comes from user side i put through this call (that's from controller):

```
public function loginAction()
{
    try {
        $this->validateInput(array('app_token', 'email', 'password', 'client_ip'));

        .....
```

All my controllers are extending BaseController, which has this function (called 1 line up):

```
/*
     * Check var from request
     */
    public function validateInput($fields)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            if ($this->request->get($field) === null) {
                $error_hint = "Add '$field' to your request.'";
                throw new Exception($this->make_api_error('#g654f', 'MISSING_INPUT_' . strtoupper($field), $error_hint));
            } else {
                $validation_result = $this->validate_input->validate_field($field, $this->request->get($field));
                if (!$validation_result) {
                    $error_hint = "Value of '$field' is invalid.";
                    if ($field == 'password') {
                        $error_hint .= ' Password must be from 7 to 50 characters in length.';
                    } else {
                        $error_hint .= ' Value submitted: ' . $this->request->get($field) . '.';
                    }
                    if ($field == 'app_token') {
                        $error_hint .= ' Contact us if your app token is not working.';
                    }
                    throw new Exception($this->make_api_error('#g3456', 'INVALID_INPUT_' . strtoupper($field), $error_hint));
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

and that's it. I now know, that i can use all these vars anywhere I need to. If it was invalid, script already returned error response about input. I can use it in my models, controllers or anywhere, because first line in all actions is validation of all input. Every single field goes though validation.